# Override single API endpoint locally

Tags: rest, api, networking, postman

Is it possible to override a single API end-point locally?

i.e:

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
```

To this one:

```
http://localhost:3000/todos/1
```

But without touching others end-point like:

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/movie/1
```

I'm trying to find a tool to do this, I also tried to use the hosts file but it work only domain by domain, not for a single API endpoint.

Comment: That is simple I think, you can create two environment variables-local and live and use them whenever you want!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Map Remote](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/map-remote/) function in [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/). I believe similar feature exists in other HTTP proxy tool such as Fiddler too.

First, configure Map Remote and mapping `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` to `http://localhost:3000`, limit the path to `/todos/*`, so that it won't impact `/movie/1`:

[image]

Then, as Charles is trying to intercept HTTPS site, you need to enable "SSL Proxying" and add `jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` (Otherwise, browser will ignore the interceptor or just throw a certificate warning):

[image]

It's done. In browser, access to `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1` or `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2` will be redirected to `http://localhost:/todos/1` or `http://localhost:3000/todos/2` internally, while access to `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/movie/1` is not touched.